# Search Not Working In Dynamic Bootstrap Multiselect

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using 
http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/ for creating bootstrap multiselect controls in my webpage.

The below fiddle link with static data is what I want to achieve using dynamic data:

https://jsfiddle.net/DROCKS/mrmLrsad/4/

```
//please refer the fiddle
```

The search option works fine in case the values of the select box are static, but if they are dynamically created, the multiselect gets created. However the search filter is not working in this case. However the my code is similar to the fiddle below, the only difference being that the search filter part doesn't work in my actual code, but works in this fiddle.

fiddle link with dynamic data.
https://jsfiddle.net/DROCKS/mrmLrsad/5/

```
//please refer the fiddle
```

This is my code.
HTML code

```
<select id="lstFieldList" ></select>
```

jQuery code [Updated]:

```
function uncheckFields(field_id)
{
    $('#' + field_id).multiselect('deselectAll', true);
}

//json_obj is the value from the fiddle.

createMultiSelectBox(json_obj);

//this function creates the multiselect
function createMultiSelectBox(json_obj)
{
    var element_String = "";
    var default_ele_set = 0;
    var def_element_first = "1";                            //if the first Y flag should be considered
    var def_element_last = "n";                             //if the last Y flag should be considered
    var def_element = def_element_first;            //change the value here to toggle between default selection
    var tmp = [];

    for (var key in json_obj)
    {
        var val = json_obj[key];
        //alert("Key: " + key);

        var chk_box_ctr = 0;
        var element;

        for(var child_key in val)
        {
            //alert("key: " + child_key + "\nvalue: " + val[child_key]);

            var default_value = child_key.split(",")[7];

            //alert("default_value: " + default_value);

            if(!chk_box_ctr)
            {
                g_max_PageSize = child_key.split(",")[8];
                //alert("g_max_PageSize: " + g_max_PageSize);
            }

            if(def_element == def_element_first)
            {
                if(default_value == "Y" && !default_ele_set)
                {
                    //element_String += '<option value="' + child_key + '" selected="selected">' + val[child_key] + '</option>';
                    element = {"label": val[child_key],"value":child_key};
                }
                else
                {
                    //element_String += '<option value="' + child_key + '">' + val[child_key] + '</option>';
                    element = {"label": val[child_key],"value":child_key};
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(default_value == "Y")
                {
                    //element_String += '<option value="' + child_key + '" selected="selected">' + val[child_key] + '</option>';
                    element = {"label": val[child_key],"value":child_key};
                }
                else
                {
                    //element_String += '<option value="' + child_key + '">' + val[child_key] + '</option>';

                    element = {"label": val[child_key],"value":child_key};
                }
            }
            tmp.push(element);
        }

        if(def_element == def_element_last)
        {
            uncheckFields('lstFieldList');
        }
    }

    //$('#lstFieldList').append(element_String);

    //$('#lstFieldList').multiselect('rebuild');

    $("#lstFieldList").multiselect('dataprovider', tmp);

    $('#lstFieldList').multiselect({
        maxHeight: 200,
        buttonWidth:"100%",
        enableFiltering:true,
        enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering:true,
        /*maxHeight: 200,
        enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
        //enableFiltering: true,
        onChange: function(option, checked, select) {
            alert('Changed option ' + $(option).val() + '.' + "\nchecked: " + checked + "\nselect: " + select);

            if(checked)
            {
                //uncheckFields('lstFieldList');
            }
            else
            {
                uncheckFields('lstFieldList');
            }
        }*/
    });

    var elem = $('#lstFieldList').next();
    elem.attr('class',(elem.attr('class') + ' open'));
}
```

What could be the problem? because the same code is present in both the files.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where is your actual code?

Comment: Hello @Anoop LL i've editted the question and added my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found out what was causing the unusual behavior in the code related to the bootstrap multiselect plugin. The code given to me by Anoop was right, I also tried various different codes related to the same plugin in the past months, but I later drop the idea to use the plugin.

Then lately last week while reworking on the same code, I identified that I had included some js script files in my html page. So I tried commenting out each include statement for the files in my html to identify which one was causing the issue. So on doing so I reached at a particular js file.

Once the file was identified, I just needed to find out which function was causing the problem to the suggestion logic of the plugin. So to identify this, I kept on commenting/removing the functions till I arrived to the function that caused the issue. There was a code related to window.setTimeout. It was due to this function that the existing suggestion logic was not working as the code was coming into this block. So I later added some flagging logic to avoid running this function in my case.

Thanks a lot all for your inputs.....

Answer (score 2):

create an array `var tmp = [];`

create a json like this while looping for option

```
element = {"label": this.Name,"value":this.id};
```

and push each element to tmp

```
tmp.push(element);
```

and pass this `tmp` array to multi select

```
$("#lstFieldList").multiselect('dataprovider', tmp);
```

and add multiselect to dropdown by

```
 $("#lstFieldList").multiselect({
                              maxHeight: 260,
                              buttonWidth:"100%",
                              enableFiltering:true,
                              enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering:true,
                            });
```

Comment: Hello @Anoop LL, I'm getting the values in the dropdown using your method however the search filter is not visible. How can i add the filter in this code as well.

Comment: the dropdown is visible with the values however it is without the search criteria still. I've added the code code that you've given right after the dataprovider multiselect line. I can't filter out entries as per the user's input.

Comment: Hello @Anoop LL, I've updated the latest code in the jQuery section of my question.

Comment: The latest code i have added na, you need to  give it before calling createMultiSelectBox function. Everything else looks fine